# Torrent clients making file system write protected

Tags: filesystem, bittorrent, read-only

IDK whats happening with the torrent clients. When I start torrent client after sometime my entire file system read only, write protected. Not able to do anything. Again I need to restart the system. Im new to ubuntu.

Comment: Sounds as if the filesystem or disk is broken. When the system encounters a write or read error it may write-lock the mount point. Can you please post output of `mount` and `dmesg |tail -n 50` when it is write protected again.

Comment: When its write protected I couldn't do any thing, only mouse will work. All window automatically will close.

Comment: Try switching to the console: Ctrl+alt+f2 for example. There you can log in as well.